# From a DOMString to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, file, dom

I'm new with javascript.
I want to know if there is a possibility to convert a DOMString (taken by reading a file saved in the Filesystem) and converting it into an Array, since I need it to perform an operation.
I'm using `e.target.result` to read the content of the file, and the result is

```
{element: "one", value: "one"},
{element: "two", value: "two"},
{...},
{...}
```

and I need the array saved in this way

```
var array = [{element: "one", value: "one"},
            {element: "two", value: "two"},
            {...},
            {...}]
```

any Idea how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add how exactly does the input you have, look?

Comment: Exactly the output of the reading, that should be also the input for the array is `[{element: "one", value: "one"},
{element: "two", value: "two"},
{...},
{...}]` I've tryed to simply assign it to an array variable but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you might give the split() function a try.

```
var prearray = '{element: "one", value: "one"},{element: "two", value: "two"}';
var realarray = prearray.split(",");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: `string.split(',')` will also split `element` and `value` into their own arrays.

Comment: I have tried with String.split(',') but as said, it splits the first array in 2 array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to do this for you:

```
var array = eval("["+item+"]");
array[0].element //"one"
array[0].value //"one"
array[1].element //"two"
array[1].value //"two"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/NZwAx/

Warning, eval can be extremely dangerous (code injection if from a third party, notoriously hard to debug if anything more complex than this example and also can have performance issues): https://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/2469255 so ensure you trust the source of the data that you are `eval`'ing

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's a great idea. the only problem is that now, when I try to execute it, also adding `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"` in the manifest file, an error occours: **Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

Comment: In that case, writing a custom parser looks to be your best option.